# UIViewController Is Not Working

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

This behavior is very odd. Every time I create a new project in Xcode 5.0.2 I cannot get it to work fully. Once the Single View Application template (or another) is created - everything seems OK: I have my delegate, storyboards and ViewController. They all run successfully and I can even see newly added UIView's in my Simulator.

Her is my generic code for ViewController:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface ViewController : UIViewController{
  UIView *container;
}
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIView *container;
@end

#import "ViewController.h"
@interface ViewController (){}
@end
@implementation ViewController
@synthesize container;
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"App loaded");
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}
@end
```

But once I add properties to this controller class and synthesize them, the screen turns black during app running and no views or whatever was added before is ever seen anymore. Just a blank black color screen.

Where is the problem? Please note:

- I checked Info*.plist and it points to Storyboard correctly
- In delegate my didFinishLaunchingWithOptions returns YES
- ViewController has a Initial View Controller checked and is the only one in the storyboard
- viewDidLoad prints NSLog message successfully even though nothing is shown

What to check?

Here is a link to the [project](http://ustymenko.name/idev/DraggableCorner.zip)

Comment: You'll have to show the actual code. If all you do is add some properties to a class and everything stops working, show us what you added. This question can't be answered as it stands. What happens if you pause the app in the debugger? It sounds like it might be looping somewhere.

Comment: I added a link above to the project. There is really no much code. I added a UIView property and synthesized it.

Comment: Can you update your question with the code, in that case? It's better if a question stands on its own rather then requiring a zip file.

Comment: What version of iOS simulator are you using?

Comment: iOS Simulator Version 7.0 (463.9.4.2)

Comment: I added all code from the file. I think it has to do with some settings but I cannot find what else to check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The view controller properties thing is a complete red herring.

You're using a storyboard for your app, which has all of the relevant details in it. Then, in your app delegate, you've added a load of code to load in a new instance of the view controller and set it as your app's root view controller.

You don't need to do this if you have a storyboard. Just return YES from `applicationDidFinishLaunching..` (which was originally the case, since you included the git history in the download!). The initial view controller from your storyboard will already be loaded up. What you've done is to basically ignore the storyboard.

Answer (score 4):

A view controller is just that, a controller.  The UIViewController's `view` property is what is visible on the screen (assuming you added it to the screen at some point, storyboard, programatic, xib, etc...)

Check the UIViewcontroller.view.superview.  You should be able to get close to what you want.

Comment: Sorry I modified my post with actual problem. I apologize for incorrect statement before.